# How to run Python Script in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I'm trying to run Python Script in Pyspark on cloudera VM

First I run pyspark by

```
$ which pyspark
$ pyspark
```

After launching the spark, i tried:

```
$ spark-submit /home/cloudera/test.py
```

Gives me "name 'spark' is not defined"

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit /home/cloudera/test.py
```

Gives me "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

I know there are many similiar questions online but I still can't figure it out. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to run the spark-submit shell from the cluster itself. You do not have to pyspark into it.

If you want to run the code interactively (type line by line or copy/paste)then you would use pyspark.

Answer (score 0):

Check spark is installed as expected by invoking spark-shell. Also try PySpark Shell and try to test whats in your test.py file. Once you are successful try spark-submit